# MKMapView black second screen, messed up keyboard in iOS 7

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

This is a copy and paste of what I posted to the [Apple Developer Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/868737):

I have an app that is working as expected in iOS 6, but I wanted to use some of the new map features of iOS 7.  When I have a second screen active, I have the following symptoms:

1. The second screen is all black except for the "Current Location" marker (the second screen holds an MKMapView).
2. The "Current Location" marker on the first screen has a black (non-transparent) box underneath it.
3. The keyboard is black, with only a few keys displaying.

Here is what the bottom of the primary screen looks like when the second screen is active:
[image]

Here is what the second screen looks like:
[image]

And here is what the first screen looks like when the second screen is not active:
[image]

The second screen is activated in my App Delegate. Here is the code that handles that:

```
NSUInteger screenCount = [[UIScreen screens] count];

if( screenCount > 1 )
{
    self.extScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
    self.availableModes = [self.extScreen availableModes];
    self.extScreen.currentMode = [self.availableModes lastObject];

    self.extScreen.overscanCompensation = UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetBounds;

    // Size of window has changed
    if( self.extWindow == nil || !CGRectEqualToRect( self.extWindow.bounds, [extScreen bounds] ) )
    {
        self.extWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[self.extScreen bounds]];

        self.extWindow.screen = self.extScreen;
    }

    CGRect masterFrame = [self.extScreen bounds];
    self.contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:masterFrame];

    self.ssMapView = [[SSMapView alloc] init];
    [ssMapView drawInView:self.contentView];

    self.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.extWindow addSubview:contentView];

    [self.extWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why the second screen is black, and even more puzzling, why does the presence of the second screen affect the look of the keyboard and the Current Location Marker on the first screen?

I would be grateful if anyone has any clues as to where I should look. I'll post more code if anyone feels that it's relevant.

Also, none of this code is specific to iOS 7, so I am not posting anything here that is under NDA. 100% of what you see below came from a working iOS 6 application that quit working as expected with compiling for iOS 7 being the only difference.

Comment: I submitted a bug report with Apple when iOS 7 GM was released, but haven't heard back.